# PrimeFaces carousel seems to display a max number of records

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I seem to have a problem with PrimeFaces carousel having a cut off point for displaying records. For instance I have 34 records of Users on my database but the carousel only seems to render 31, after which the panel still scroll along but does not display any details[Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lta7i.png) 
I have tried changing the numVisible attribute to see if it makes any difference.
Does anyone know if this is a problem with the PrimeFaces framework?

Comment: Look in the PrimeFaces source... Easy to do... Make sure you look in the right version... And check the browser developer tooling for error etc...

Comment: Hi. Had a look at the PF source code, especially the Carousel java files in the component folder. There didn't seem to be anything that immediately stood out as the problem. Cheers @Kukeltje

Comment: There are also .js files. Maybe there is something in there... and maybe your images are just not loaded

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje. I think I have the solution. Its in the carousel.css file within the Manifest directory. The width has to be increased from 32000px to 100000px.  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/705. Thanks for the help.